# Magento 2 filter not working on custom customer attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer-attribute

I have created custom customer attribute. It is displaying in customer grid in admin panel but when I try to filter on my custom attribute, I get error

> **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_attribute' in 'where clause'.**

This is because it's not available in  table **customer_grid_flat**
I have already done re-indexing.

When I change value of **is_used_in_grid** to **1** from table **customer_eav_attribute** and start re indexing i am getting following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source::addAttributeToSelect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento-221/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/Handler/AttributeHandler.php:38

I have tried changing following column value to 1 but not working.

```
is_visible_in_grid
is_filterable_in_grid
is_searchable_in_grid
```

Here is setup file code

```
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_approval',
            [
            'label' => 'Customer Approve',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 108,
            'sort_order' =>108,
            'visible' =>  false,
            'note' => 'Customer Approval',


                        'type' => 'int',
                        'input' => 'boolean',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'customer_approval')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']) -> save();


    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong with that.

Comment: Use `addFieldToSelect` instead of addAttributeToSelect. 

`addFieldToSelect` used for flat model

`addAttributeToSelect` user for EAV model

Comment: @magefms I am not using any custom filter coding. When customer attribute create, it will display under filter option in admin

Comment: can you share your updradedata.php or installdata.php files,

Comment: @AnandOntigeri I have update code in my question.

Comment: I have answered your question, I think the problem with options and is_used_in_grid , if you want to see this filed in grid is_used_in_grid should be yes "is_used_in_grid =1) then only you can apply filter in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to delete the attribute from the system and try the below code:

I think the problem with options and is_used_in_grid if you want to see this field in the grid is_used_in_grid should be yes (is_used_in_grid =1) then only you can apply the filter in the grid.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_approval', [
            'type'           => 'int',
            'label'          => 'customer approval',
            'input'          => 'bool',
            'option'         => ['values' => ['0', '1']],
            'source'         => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required'       => 0,
            'sort_order'     => 210,
            'visible'        => 0,
            'position'       => 300,
            'admin_checkout' => 1,
            'system'         => 0,
            'is_null'        => false,
            'user_defined'   => true,
            'is_system'      => 0,
            'is_used_in_grid'              => 1,
            'is_visible_in_grid'           => 1,
            'is_filterable_in_grid'        => 1,
            'is_searchable_in_grid'        => 1,
            'is_used_for_customer_segment' => 1,
        ]);
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_approval');
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_form_attribute'],
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
}
```

Comment: I have add above code in installData.php and run setup upgrade command. I am getting error Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\module name\Setup\InstallData::$customerSetupFactory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento-221/app/code/MES/CustomerApproval/Setup/InstallData.php on line 48

Comment: On line 48 $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]); code is writtent

Comment: in constructor did you mentioned Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

Comment: public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

Comment: After update constructor code now, i get error "We can't find the role for the user you wanted."

Comment: where? in admin?

Comment: While run setup upgrade command. But i think i have stop setup upgrade process once manually. After that i am getting this error. So i have add module in different magento setup. Now i am getting error  Vendor\Module anme\Setup\AttributeSetFactory does not exist

Comment: sorry include this one use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory

Comment: actually i have written "use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;" in my file .. i didnot noticed that one

Comment: Now, i am getting error Uncaught Error: Class 'Vendor\ModuleApproval\Setup\Customer' not found in magento root/app/code/Vendor/Module name/Setup/InstallData.php:57 On Line 57 code is  $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_approval', [

Comment: I think issue comes because of Customer:ENTITY

Comment: I have fixed that by changing \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer Now setup upgrade run. But my custom attribute drop down comes with no value. It should be Yes/No

Comment: delete attribue and remove line 'option'         => ['values' => ['0', '1']], and try

Comment: I have removed that and try again. but blank drown comes. So i have create new customer and get dropdown value as expected. Now, my main issue is still there. When is_used_in_grid = 1 in database, i am getting same error while indexing. When i make it 0, indexing run properly. But in that case my attribute not comes in  table customer_grid_flat so, i am not able to use for filter data.

Comment: I found my solution here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10838#issuecomment-332802984